# Unity/Vuforia: No WebCam Profile

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using the same computer and unity project, but suddenly today my AR Camera isn't showing me the webcam feed. I am getting the following error:

[![enter image description here]

My web cam works fine (checked from the driver software). Also the webcam deviceName (the type of webcam) is in the profiles, which it mentions from the error message.

*** I think the error might be in the path Vuforia is looking. In the error message its saying Assets\Editor/QCAR (not: Assets\Editor\QCAR) ***  ... This being said I have not idea how to point it in the right direction as I can't edit the Web Cam Behaviour Script ...

Has anyone come across this before?

NOTE: am using Unity 64 (but this was not a problem before!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and opening in Unity 32-bit solved the problem. Still if anyone has an idea of why the error was there in the first place, please do comment

Comment: Hi. This likely occurred because all Vuforia versions BEFORE Vuforia 6 were only compatible with Unity 32 bit. If you want to use 64 bit, upgrade to Unity 5.4 and Vuforia 6